# Separate csv ";" in columns VBA(SQL)

Tags: excel, vba

I made code that imports (using ODBC / VBA) CSV files. However, they appear separated in several columns by the ";" tab.

How can I separate each individual column? (LOOK DE SAMPLE IMAGE BELOW)

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you can just split them using the semi-colon `;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: Might you replace the commas (tabs) with semi-colons before you create the sheet? Or don't specify tab as a separator? If you can't do anything before sheet creation, the CONCAT or CONCATENATE function (or simple `=A1&A2&A3)` should join the cells in a helper column.

Comment: Maybe your file is not a CSV-formatted file, but a semicolon-delimited one?  The commas in the file may be decimal separators.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved it using the CONCATENATE function and grouped them all in the first column.